# Parse-Server, Nodejs + ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-server

I'm just started using [Parse-Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) at `index.js` there is:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

My problem is that at the client I'm forced to view `index.html` under `url/public` or use:

`<base href="public/">`

For now since I removed `app.use` first argument path will be executed for every request to the app, what I'm not sure is...

1. Is this the right way to go?
2. Is it better to use `<base href="public/">`?
3. Can my change affect the server?

I really don't want to destroy something that will bite me later so any suggestion or good practice will be welcomed.

Comment: If you want to have index.html from this url  http://locahost/index.html.
you have use app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: @AnthonyC I already know that(it's part of my question), basically what I try to avoid is doing changes that will mess up Parse-Server or express bad-practice